# Visual Studio 2012 Express debugging explorer.exe - no breakpoint hit

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints, windows-explorer

I have problem with debugging SolidWorks Enterprise PDM addin. I don't know how the addins are handled within EPDM, but the problem seems to be related with Visual Studio - maybe someone else has similar problem with other platform's addins.

Adding a debug addin (so that latest source is used):
[image: PDM debug addin]

In Visual Studio 2010 Express there's no problem - kill explorer, start it, attach to it and:
[image: VS2010 debugging successful]

I couldn't achieve the same with Visual Studio 2012 Express. Although it seems that it is debugging explorer (files are read-only, stop debug button is shown), it doesn't hit breakpoints:
[image: VS2012 debugging failure]

I work on Windows 7 Professional x64. Addins are built with .NET 3.5. I've used both VS2010 and VS2012 solutions with the same problem.

I do restart explorer.exe, so the latest version of addin is loaded. Project uses start action "explorer.exe":

```
    <StartAction>Program</StartAction>
    <StartProgram>$(windir)\explorer.exe</StartProgram>
    <StartArguments></StartArguments>
```

I don't know why the breakpoints are not hit, any help much appreciated.

Thanks!

## UPDATE 1

I've checked what Hans suggested - there are two other processes starting, but attaching to them didn't result in anything.

That pointed out one more thing - when I was attaching to those processes there was an information within VisualStudio, that the breakpoints will not be hit, because no debug symbols were loaded - notice that in [the third image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBPEk.png) the debug symbols are loaded (the red circle is filled and without the exclamation mark).

## UPDATE 2

When I attached VisualStudio to the managed explorer.exe - the breakpoints were hit!

It seems that explorer.exe is running in Managed mode only sometimes:
[image: explorer.exe in different modes]

It can even be running in both modes side by side:
[image: explorer.exe in two modes]

So the question is how to force VisualStudio starting explorer.exe in managed mode?

## UPDATE 3

Is it possibly a VisualStudio 2012 bug?

When debugging with VS2010 the explorer is started in normal mode, but as soon as the addin is loaded, it is switched to managed mode and VS2010 stops at the breakpoints.

With VS2012 it is different - when the addin is loaded, explorer.exe is not switched to managed mode and (therefore? is it connected?) breakpoints are not hit.

But when VS2012 is attached to the explorer.exe that already is in managed mode, it stops at breakpoints.

## UPDATE 4

I've managed to reach the essence of the problem - when attaching VS2012 to another process (e.g. explorer.exe) with "Automatically determine the type of code to debug" selected" and the process is started in native mode and some time later loads managed code - the debugger doesn't stop at the breakpoints. When the process is already in managed mode when attaching to or when attaching to with code type(s) explicitly selected ("Managed (v3.5, v3.0, v2.0)") - the debugger stops at the breakpoints.

Already posted on [connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/768361/) - awaiting solution. Please vote if you experience the same problem as described in this update.

## UPDATE 5

I've just tested it on [a simple managed shell extension](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/174369/How-to-Write-Windows-Shell-Extension-with-NET-Lang) so it is not SolidWorks Enterprise PDM - related.

I've also posted [a more precise bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/769118/) on connect.

## UPDATE 6

As of the beginning of 2013 Microsoft claims that it is a **design decision** that **the debugger is not behaving as expected**. More details in the first connect bug report.

Comment: It makes *very* little sense to kill and restart Explorer to debug a vendor specific plug-in model.  Start the vendor's app instead.  Contact that vendor for support.

Comment: EPDM installs as Windows Explorer extension - that's why I'm debugging explorer.exe (it worked for VS2010). I'll verify if there are any other processes that are starting with it.

Answer (score 1):

When you're building a `.dll` (I assume this way it's loaded into explorer) breakpoints had always problems (at least in my experience), because you have no way of knowing in advance where file will be loaded in memory, therefore it's hard to add a breakpoint.

You may try to add manual [breakpoint invocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_%28x86_instruction%29#INT_3) inside your code (which is `int3`). In C++ this would be:

```
asm {
    int 3;
}
```

In C# [there's a method for that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx):

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()
```

Try to adding to the beginning of your function/code part (don't forget co compile in **debug mode**).

Then you'll just start debugging application (`.exe`) which loads `.dll` file and loaded library should trigger a break point.

Comment: adding Debugger.Break(); didn't stop VisualStudio

Comment: Very useful method... just don't forget to compile in DEBUG mode.

Comment: @marchewek do you have Debug build? Are you sure that your function is loaded? Have you tried another debugger?

Comment: I use Debug mode and I wrote the debug symbols are loaded (so the function is) and I wrote that in VS2010 everything works fine.

Comment: @marchewek what happens if you try to start explorer in (lets say) OllyDbg? This seems like some "mental issues" on side of visual studio.

Comment: I've downloaded ollydbg but it seems to support 32bit apps only.

Comment: Does anyone have some time to test it on a direct explorer extension?

Comment: @marchewek this looks like a bug in VS to me

Comment: @Vyktor it looks like a bug to me as well. But unfortunately not to MS.

Comment: Related: [Breakpoints for debugging an EPDM Add-in in VS 2013 Express](https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/97036).  The gist of it is to make sure you choose the right debugger in the `attach to` part of the dialog for the framework version of *your* program.  E.g. If you are writing in .Net 4 then you would choose `Managed (v.4.5,4.0)`